# JPQL Many-to-many Dto select failure

Tags: spring, hibernate, many-to-many, jpql, dto

I want to write JPQL query for selecting a DoctorDto from my  AppUserRepository. There is a many-to-many relationship between AppUser and Specialization entity. The two entities are presented below:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "app_user")
public class AppUser  {
    

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "doctor_specialization", joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "app_user_id")}, inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "specialization_id")})
    private Set<Specialization> specializations;

}

@Entity
@Table(name="specialization")
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Specialization {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String name;

}
```

I have created a DoctorDto object:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class DoctorDto {
   
   private Set<Specialization> specializations;

   public DoctorDto(Set<Specialization> specializations){
      this.specializations = specializations;
   }

}
```

I would like to select all the doctors with their specializations from my AppUserRepository. In order to do that, I have written the following JPQL query:

```
 @Query("select new com.my-package.DoctorDto(u.specializations) from AppUser u")
 List<DoctorDto> getDoctors();
```

However, I am receiving an error:

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'as'.
```

The Hibernate query looks as follows:

```
Hibernate: select . as col_0_0_ from app_user appuser0_ inner join doctor_specialization specializa1_ on appuser0_.id=specializa1_.app_user_id inner join specialization specializa2_ on specializa1_.specialization_id=specializa2_.id
```

As you can see, it seems that specializations are not detected by Hibernate. Everything works perfectly fine without Dto mapping. What is the reason for this error? How can I fix it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you cannot get collections like that. You will have to explicity join tables in your query

Comment: Can you specify how you would implement this? When it comes to non-Dto examples such as: "select u.specializations from AppUser u", it works fine. I have tried joining tables in my query, but without success.

Comment: Try one these work arounds.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52452550/load-child-collection-dtos-in-jpa-dto-projection-query

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible out of the box like bluelurker answered already, but I think this is a perfect use case for [Blaze-Persistence Entity Views](https://github.com/Blazebit/blaze-persistence#entity-view-usage).

I created the library to allow easy mapping between JPA models and custom interface or abstract class defined models, something like Spring Data Projections on steroids. The idea is that you define your target structure(domain model) the way you like and map attributes(getters) via JPQL expressions to the entity model.

A DTO model for your use case could look like the following with Blaze-Persistence Entity-Views:

```
@EntityView(AppUser.class)
public interface DoctorDto {
    @IdMapping
    Long getId();
    Set<SpecializationDto> getSpecializations();

    @EntityView(Specialization.class)
    interface SpecializationDto {
        @IdMapping
        Long getId();
        String getName();
    }
}
```

Querying is a matter of applying the entity view to a query, the simplest being just a query by id.

`DoctorDto a = entityViewManager.find(entityManager, DoctorDto.class, id);`

The Spring Data integration allows you to use it almost like Spring Data Projections: https://persistence.blazebit.com/documentation/entity-view/manual/en_US/index.html#spring-data-features

```
Page<DoctorDto> findAll(Pageable pageable);
```

The best part is, it will only fetch the state that is actually necessary!