# Is it possible to run a query for construct an object with list<>

Tags: jpa, jpql

I'm trying to find a way to create an object from a query, this object is containing three int fields and a List<>

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
public class SiteDescriptionDao {

    private int        hauteurMax;
    private int        cotMin;
    private int        cotMax;
    private List<Voie> voieList;

}
```

my 'actual' query is :

```
SELECT new com.c.c.c.dao.SiteDescriptionDao(1,1,1,(select vo from Voie vo where vo
.idSecteur = 1)) FROM Site si
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2355728/jpql-create-new-object-in-select-statement-avoid-or-embrace

Comment: It's not possible to return a list in an row of a query.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JPQL: Receiving a Collection in a Constructor Expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5998409/jpql-receiving-a-collection-in-a-constructor-expression)