# How do i make a spring Data projection take a collection that is a relationship as an argument?

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

So i have this @Entity

```
public class RecipeDAO extends AbstractDAO {

    private Boolean visible;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "recipes", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<TopicDAO> topics;

    @MapKey(name = "id.locale")
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "recipe", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private Map<String, Localization> localizations;

    @MapKey(name = "id.locale")
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "recipe", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private Map<String, JsonData> json;
}
```

and in the repository interface i have this @Query:

```
@Query("select new com.fullstack.dtos.RecipeDTO(t.id, t.createdBy, t.lastModifiedBy, t.created, t.lastModified, t.version, t.visible, l.title, l.description, l.footnote, topics) from recipes t inner join t.localizations l inner join t.topics topics where l.id.locale = :lang and l.title like %:title%")
    Page<RecipeDTO> findAllByTitle(String lang, String title, Pageable pageable);
```

This is a multi-lingue system hence the localizations and json in maps representing multiple languages and this query works if i don't include topics. Now if i do include topics i cant seem to find a way to put them into the projection class.
If i use Collection (or List or Set) it says the type isnt the same and expects TopicDAO. If i include topicDAO if finds all topics but assigns a topic to a recipe
This is a set of logs i made:

```
TopicDAO(id=1771b663-e5d2-4a09-a758-9dec919cb3c6, topic=savory)
TopicDAO(id=1de01b0d-b01c-42da-a5c5-78b2048b8f1a, topic=cheap)
TopicDAO(id=342fdc0d-a091-4669-9753-69c6b9293562, topic=not vegan)
TopicDAO(id=46ad594e-4aaf-4438-90fc-7401fca4fda4, topic=nice)
TopicDAO(id=67477796-4a6d-4b48-9c69-c9692d341d7a, topic=easy)
TopicDAO(id=be7a016d-7d6f-4cd1-a1ab-4faadf484c30, topic=nutritious)
TopicDAO(id=c29347bd-e755-4414-9a63-28f70a2498cb, topic=meat)
TopicDAO(id=d28cbaba-cd24-4256-8767-6cf9f75e5e1b, topic=lunch)
TopicDAO(id=f845f510-15ad-471e-8cfb-6b46d0ab1ec6, topic=dinner)
TopicDAO(id=fa97c9be-346b-435f-a8a1-4400c13f26cd, topic=breakfast)

Page 1 of 1 containing com.fullstack.dtos.RecipeDTO instances
[RecipeDTO(visible=true, topics=["easy"]), RecipeDTO(visible=true, topics=["breakfast"]), RecipeDTO(visible=true, topics=["nice"]), RecipeDTO(visible=true, topics=["lunch"]), RecipeDTO(visible=true, topics=["not vegan"]), RecipeDTO(visible=true, topics=["dinner"]), RecipeDTO(visible=true, topics=["cheap"]), RecipeDTO(visible=true, topics=["meat"]), RecipeDTO(visible=true, topics=["savory"]), RecipeDTO(visible=true, topics=["nutritious"])]
```

Now in the projection im mapping a TopicDAO to the Set basically using Set.of from the set interface. and it works. The problem is says page 1 of 1 because the database **only** **has one item** so spring is basically replicating the recipe for as many topics as it has. If i include more info on the prints, it all matches, including the @Id of the recipe meaning is the same. Is there any keywork in JPQL im missing to force this topics to go into a Collection of some sort?
I even have SQL queries being logged from hibernate and it does a select * from topics where... multiple times (one for each topic) instead of selecting and returning as a collection

**EDIT:** AbstractDAO is a common parent to all my daos, and AbstractDTO a parent to all dtos that just contain the stuff that is global like the @Id, @Created, @CreatedBy, @Version fields

**EDIT 2:** I have also tried with interface based projections the result is the same, it all ends up separated eacly the same way, 10 objects in the page with each topic (basically 10 replicas of the recipe one for each topic).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JPQL: Receiving a Collection in a Constructor Expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5998409/jpql-receiving-a-collection-in-a-constructor-expression)

Comment: I mean, there they just show there constructors don't take collections and they fetch the collection in another query afterwards. If anything that should there might not be a solution to this in particular no?

Comment: Sure, thats a valid workaround.